# Fortran - Passing a variable into CGESV

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am trying to test the LAPACK method CGESV, but I am encountering an issue. I want to reuse my 'A' matrix in other parts of my code, but it changes when I pass it into the method. The definition of 'A':

```
(input/output) COMPLEX array, dimension (LDA,N)
      On entry, the N-by-N coefficient matrix A.
      On exit, the factors L and U from the factorization
      A = P*L*U; the unit diagonal elements of L are not stored.
```

Is there a way to keep the value of A after passing it into CGESV short of creating a temp variable to store the value?

Comment: In my experience, no. The routines tend to clobber the stuff you send in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed the `A` matrix is overwritten with `P*L*U` decomposition. If the size of the matrix is not so big, you can copy the contents of `A` matrix and use the copy for the decomposition.

```
         CALL CCOPY(N*N, A, 1, A_NEW, 1)
```

If the matrix size is so big that you can not keep two copies of it in memory, you can perform the math operations with the decomposed matrix. For example to compute `y=A*x`

```
*        y = x
         CALL CCOPY(N, X, 1, Y, 1)
*        y = U * y
         CALL CTRMV('Upper', 'No transpose', 'Non-unit', N, A, N, Y, 1)
*        y = L * y
         CALL CTRMV('Lower', 'No transpose', 'Unit', N, A, N, Y, 1)
*        y = P * y
         CALL DLASWP( 1, Y, N, 1, N, IPIV, 1 )
```

The additional memory needed is the integer `IPIV` sized `N`.

Comment: I do use large matrices in my code so thank you for the alternate method. My question to you is which is faster: Copying the matrix or recovering the matrix as you have? Also why do you use CCOPY? wouldn't A_NEW=A accomplish the same thing?

Comment: If you need to perform several operation using `A` after `CGESV` then coping is definitely faster. I would recommended the alternative method in the case you encounter memory limitations. I used `CCOPY` just for compliance with BLAS/LAPACK usage, plus I do not know how `A` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The routines do their work in-place, so the only way to keep the original array is to make a copy.